# Die Lautschrift zu Chopin

Tags: pronunciation, loanword

Ich finde derzeit keine Referenz für die Aussprache des Namens "Chopin" - in Deutsch.
Im Englischen Wikipedia Artikel finde ich Referenzen für:
Englisch: ʃoʊpæn
Französisch:ʃɔ.pɛ̃

Die Aussprache wird mir auf folgenden Seiten differenziel nahegelegt:

- [linguatec.net](http://www.linguatec.net/onlineservices/voice_reader/) - Aussprache: Schopahng
- [Google Translater](http://translate.google.de/#fr/en/Chopin) - Aussprache (Wahl Französisch): Schopah

Comment: For a laugh: try to change Google Translate's target language to *Latin*. It will translate "Chopin" to "Mozart", and speak it with a strong Russian accent ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Deutschen richtet man sich nach der französischen Aussprache.

[ ʃoˈpɛ̃ː ] laut [Duden Online.](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Chopin)

[ ʃɔˈpɛ̃ ] laut Theodor Siebs, *[Deutsche Hochsprache,](http://books.google.de/books?id=4bS1J50DW0gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:2GZt7RKHtT0C&hl=de&sa=X&ei=5tEZUfHoG4vGtAb95IHYAw&ved=0CDIQuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=chopin&f=false)* Ausgabe 1966.

Die polnischen Aussprachebeispiele auf [Forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/search/chopin/pl/) klingen nach [ ˈʃɔpɘn ]. Der Name ist aber wohl ursprünglich französisch. Der Vater von Frédéric Chopin war von Frankreich nach Polen eingewandert.

---

IPA-Zeichenliste in der Wikipedia: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen